# Dynamically added tag doesn't work correctly with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I try to add dynamically tag in a view. I want to use a jquery plugin as datetimepicker. (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)
This doesn't work.

```
//$("#timeseriesDate" + i + "").datetimepicker({
//    timepicker: false,
//    format: 'Y/m/d',
//    formatDate: 'Y/m/d'
//});

function create() {
    var startDate = new Date($('#date1').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#date2').val());
    var diff = datediff(startDate, endDate);
    $("#matrixtimeseries").empty();
    $("#matrixtimeseries").append('<div>');
    for (i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
        $("#matrixtimeseries").append('<input class="timeseries-red date" type="text" name=timeseriesDate' + i + 'id=timeseriesDate' + i + '"/>');
        //$("#timeseriesDate" + i + "").datetimepicker({
        //    timepicker: false,
        //    format: 'Y/m/d',
        //    formatDate: 'Y/m/d'
        //});
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 24; ii++) {
            $("#matrixtimeseries").append('<input class="timeseries-red" type="text" name=hourseries' + i + ii + 'id=hourseries' + i + ii + '" />');
        }
        $("#matrixtimeseries").append('<br/>');
    };
    $("#matrixtimeseries").append('</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space between the `name` and `id` in the generated HTML.

```
$("#matrixtimeseries").append('<input class="timeseries-red date" type="text" name=timeseriesDate' + i + ' id=timeseriesDate' + i + '"/>');
                                                                                                          ^
```

Your HTML had the following attribute when `i=1`: `name=timeseriesDate1id=timeseriesDate1`

Or you can use an object-oriented approach instead of generating HTML.

```
$("#matrixtimeseries").append($("<input>", 
    "class": "timeseries-red date",
    "type": "text",
    "name": "timeseriesDate" + i,
    "id": "timeseriesDate" + i
}));
```